# How to migrate data from MacBook Pro to new iPad Air

Tags: macos, ipados, migration-assistant

I just bought a new iPad Air and wondered if Migration Assistant is on it, and where I find it?

I am trying to move all of my data from a MacBook Pro to the iPad Air.

Answer (score 11):

There is no migration tool to import from an Mac to an iPad. Signing both in to iCloud enables bi-directional file sync as well as other structured data for select apps and files.

Also, the wired and wireless sync has grown up substantially from where it was initially using iTunes to move files to the iPhone and iPad and iPod.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/sync-ipad-with-your-computer-ipadae9bab3e/ipados

Comment: Won't an app like iExplorer allow you to transfer files?

Comment: I suppose @jmh but now that everyone knows the filesystem structure is unix based, but sandboxed, the need for transfer apps is lessened in my experience. Especially since you can mount SMB and attach bulk storage to the iPad and transfer files in and out. Perhaps I should edit that detail in.